# How to do aggregation (AVG, SUM, MAX etc.) on Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying out Azure DocumentDB and their [documentation says aggregation is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates). Indeed, I am able to do `COUNT` by:

```
SELECT value COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE c.id = 'someid'
```

However, if I follow same syntax to do other types of aggregation, it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT value MAX(value) FROM c WHERE c.id = 'someid'
```

gives error. This is same with MIN.

It looks like aggregation is not supported (even though docs says otherwise). Or is there different approach to do it?

Comment: In your example, what are you computing `MAX` of? `COUNT` returns a count of object, but wouldn't `MAX` need a property to compute from?

Comment: Yup, that's my question. `MAX(c.value)` doesn't work.

Comment: Your example doesn't have `MAX(c.value)`.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: You're getting an error because that's invalid syntax, as you left off `c.` in your property reference.

Comment: Also - in your example, is `value` really a property name? If so, you cannot access directly via `c.value` since `value` is a reserved word. Updating my answer to reference how to work around that.

Comment: Yup `value` is property name, I think that's the main issue here.

Comment: See edit at bottom of my answer for workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `MAX()` to work, you need to aggregate on a given property. For example, if you had a few documents with a `range` property:

```
{
  "id": "max1",
  "range": 50
}
{
  "id": "max2",
  "range": 20
}
```

You'd get the max value of `range` via:

```
SELECT MAX(c.range) from c
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "$1": 50
  }
]
```

Or

```
SELECT VALUE MAX(c.range) from c
```

Which returns:

```
[
  50
]
```

Note: In your question's example, you use `c.value`. `VALUE` is a reserved word, so you'd need to reference as `c['value']`. For example:

```
SELECT VALUE MAX(c['value']) from c
```

Comment: It was indeed issue with reserved keyword `value` being property name. Last example works good. Thank you.